# Logo Color in RGB Help

Tags: logo, cmyk, rgb

I have a style guide for an old company logo which we had designed years ago. In the guide there are the two main colors for the logo but only PMS and CMYK values, so i'm wondering how to figure out what color values to use when creating graphics in srgb colorspace? These are the colors:

Blue. PMS 310, 48c/0m/9y/0k
Orange. PMS 151, 0c/60m/100y/0k

I tried googling the PMS codes and found conflicting hex codes. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just use your eyes to determine matching RGB colors.

Comment: [This](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/144742/84899) is related.

Comment: There is as many solutions as there are color profiles.