# Defining Brand Colours

Tags: color-profile

I've been trying to get my head around colour management for ages. It seems like a hugely complicated topic, so I'll keep my question as simple as possible :

If the same RGB or CMYK values can result in different colours according to the colour profile, shouldn't brand guidelines always specify the ICC profile? I ask because I often see corporate guidelines that don't include this profile information. In these cases, are any particular profiles assumed?

Comment: The profile depends on the material and printer that you're using.

Comment: You are right! It's inaccurate to not specify a color profile. I also see it all the time. [This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/144742/84899) is related.

Comment: @Wolff i fail to see how not including the info makes it harder. If you dont understand you just ignore. Anyway im more inclined to think that the guide designer didnt understand CMS. Most designers suprisingly do not.

Comment: @joojaa, because clients normally don't care about or understand technical explanations. If they see colors not matching some earlier print, they might complain. And then it can become a social problem with lots of wasted time and energy.

Comment: @Wolff yes and for that reason you should care. But honestly only consumer goods packaging is actually critical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should define a standard color profile to define your colors in. Its true that most brand guides dont specify this, and yes its wrong on many levels.

- For RGB choose either sRGB, or Adobe RGB. (Avoid pro photo  as it requires more than 8 bit color to be useful or DCI P3for now).
  I suggest sRGB since web colors are assumed to be in sRGB, this causes least errors. In any case you see naked rgb values with profile info you should assume sRGB. Even if wrong because its the only sane guess to be had.
- For CMYK choose a print standard color from your area (SWOP, Euroscale...)

PS: Defining these in a footnote does not detract from simplicity just makes your definitions complete. If anybody ever even cares

PPS: Its a bit complicated topic yes. It involves things that your not generally aware to think about.